# How to create a bootstrap "row" dynamically using knockout foreach binding in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

Here is the code snippet in my cshtml file where I am using knockout loop to display content:

```
<div data-bind="visible: results().length > 0, foreach: results">    
    <div class="row">
    <!-- ko if: ImageTileSize == "2" -->    
        <div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: ImageTileSize == "1" -->    
        <div class="col-md-3">
    <!-- /ko -->
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: Link }" class="powering-article">
                <div class="powering-listimg">
                <img data-bind="attr: { src: ImageUrl }" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <p><span data-bind="    text: PublishedDate.format('DD MMM YYYY')"></span> | <strong><span data-bind="    text: Category"></span></strong></p>
                <h2 data-bind="text: Title"></h2>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: ImageTIleSize will always be 1 or 2.

What I like to do is apply counter in the for loop, so if ImageTileSize were to equal more than 4, then create another row div tag inside the loop with all the same content as above.

I am not entirely sure how to pass the knockout value to razor:

```
@int count = 0;
<div data-bind...
    @if(..

    }
    ...
    @count = count + ImageTileSize; //doesn't work, can't grab the ImageTileSize value
</div>
```

**Update:**

This is how bootstrap currently handles the row after every 12 columns:
[image]

"Article 1" should start under "Article 3", but it finds itself enough space under "Article 2". Although, if I were to add a large image like "Article 4", then it is positioned correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to note here:

- Razor code runs server side. `ImageTileSize` is a property of each object in `results` obserableArray. You can't use it with your c# `count` variable.
- Your [Containerless control flow syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html#note-using-if-without-a-container-element) is invalid. They behave like HTML elements. In your case, `div` tags don't have closing tags.

I'm assuming you want to get a new `row` for every "12-columns" of bootstrap grid system. You can do something like this:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="visible: results().length > 0, foreach: results">
    <div data-bind="attr: { class: ImageTileSize == '1' ? 'col-md-3' : 'col-md-6' }">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: Link }" class="powering-article">
            <div class="powering-listimg">
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: ImageUrl }" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <p><span data-bind="    text: PublishedDate.format('DD MMM YYYY')"></span> | <strong><span data-bind="    text: Category"></span></strong></p>
            <h2 data-bind="text: Title"></h2>
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/mbzzr72m/7/) for testing. I have changed the classes from `col-md-*` to `col-xs-*` since the result window is small and all the `col-md-` render in a new row.

Note that, this won't generate a new `<div class="row">` after every "12 columns". But bootstrap will automatically handle it. Whenever it can't fit the next `col-md-3`, it will move to the next row by default.

---

Update:

If you still want to create a new `row` for every "12-columns", then you can create a [`computed`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) property called `groupedResults`. This will be an array of arrays. Each inner array will contain the `results` for each `row`. The idea here is to loop through the `results` and group them to fit in a bootstrap `row`.

```
// this array looks: [[result1,result2,result3], [result4,result5]] based on tile width of each result
self.groupedResults = ko.computed(function() {
    var rows = [];
    var count = 0; // image tile count for current row

    self.results().forEach(function(item, i) {
      // initialize new inner array when count = 0 
      // or when the total tile count > 4
      if (count == 0 || (count + parseInt(item.ImageTileSize)) > 4) {
        rows[rows.length] = [item];
        count = parseInt(item.ImageTileSize);
      } else {
        rows[rows.length - 1].push(item);
        count += parseInt(item.ImageTileSize);
      }
    });

    return rows;
});
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div data-bind="visible: groupedResults().length > 0, foreach: groupedResults">
  <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <div style="text-align: center" data-bind="attr: { class: ImageTileSize == '1' ? 'col-md-3' : 'col-md-6' }">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: Link }" class="powering-article">
            <div class="powering-listimg">
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: ImageUrl }" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <p><span data-bind="    text: PublishedDate.format('DD MMM YYYY')"></span> | <strong><span data-bind="    text: Category"></span></strong></p>
            <h2 data-bind="text: Title"></h2>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`$data` here is the inner array in context. [You can read about binding context here.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

[Here's a fiddle for this computed implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/mbzzr72m/5/)

Comment: Hi @adiga, that was really helpful, thanks for cleaning up the code. I have edited my post to show you what it looks like after it goes over 12 columns. I thought bootstrap would handle it but wasn't sure why it wouldn't therefore I was going for adding the <div class="row"> approach. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Honestly, I am not to familiar with Knockout library, our vendor used it they don't work for us anymore. Here is jfiddle link(https://jsfiddle.net/bx9ma9zf/1/), would be able tell me where I can insert your code? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: It's fairly simple. Knockout expects a javascript object with or without `observables`. There are many ways to create an object. The one I have done is using a constructor function. In your case it;s created like this `var vm = {}`. So you'd have to add a property called `groupedResults` to it. Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bx9ma9zf/2/)

Comment: Wow, that's perfect, that basically solves my problem. One more thing, since you are an expert, I like to return the results of everything but the first item in the array, how can I do this? I use to have the <!-- ko if: $index() != 0 --> right after the for loop but I guess that doesn't work anymore..

Comment: @Vipresh inside the `forEach` you could skip the zeroth `index` like this: `self.results().forEach(function(item, i) { if(i == 0) return; <rest of the code>..... }`